# WPF: Save and read Json file in Documents folder

Tags: json, wpf, save

I'm making a simple WPF program:

How do I save json string in a data.json file in Documents folder and read them back using Json.NET?

My Code:

```
    public void SerializeTest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.Name = "Item " + i;

            productList.Add(product);
        }

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productList, Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

You can use this and append to get to your desired file.

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productList, Formatting.Indented);
 
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ExampleFolder\\ExampleSubFolder\\data.json";
        try
        {
                File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```